# ERROR: You must have the pdo_sqlite PHP extension installed (Windows) Drupal CMS

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo, drupal

I am trying out the Drupal CMS, and I wanna try it out on my local computer first so I am following this guide: https://www.drupal.org/docs/official_docs/en/_evaluator_guide.html. Drupal requires PHP to run.

I installed php 8.0.3 for Windows Zip and put it in my path file so PHP works on the command prompt.
I also installed Drupal 9.1.5 unzipped it and am currently running commands in the drupal-9.1.5 directory.

I ran the command from this set up guide thinking it would launch drupal:

> php core/scripts/drupal quick-start demo_umami

And the command prompt gave me the error:

> [ERROR] You must have the pdo_sqlite PHP extension installed See
> core/INSTALL.sqlite.txt for instructions, now I checked

so I headed over to INSTALL.sqlite.txt in the Drupal directory and it told me:

> Windows
> ------- Read more about it on http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.installation.php

I went to the website and it says that the driver is enabled by default, but since I'm getting the error, it must mean I don't have it on PHP so it told me to head over to the php.ini file. In my PHP directory, since it's a newer version it has the php.ini-development file and php.ini-production file.

The windows fix says to simply uncomment ;extension=pdo_sqlite to extension=pdo_sqlite which I did for both php.ini-development and -production files. This is where I'm stuck. I did exactly what the error told me to fix and I am still getting it. How can I fix this?
I looked around and every solution for windows is to uncomment and I still get the error.
Another thing on the php manual states that extension=php_pdo.dll, but my php.ini file does not have the extensions. does that matter?
Here are my uncommented extensions which I thought could contribute to helping the error:

- extension=php_pdo.dll
- extension=pdo_sqlite
- extension=sqlite3

One last attempt at trying to get this php command to work is installing the Windows sqlite binary and putting it into windows path (contains a dll not an exe), but that didn't help anything either.

How do I fix this. Thank you.

Comment: `php.ini-development` and `php.ini-production` only provide examples of a good configuration setup for these respective environments, but they do not actually get _used_ (by default.) You need to create your own `php.ini` (take the development version as basis.)

Answer (score 0):

Hi just make a copy of "php.ini-development" and rename it "php.ini".
And uncomment the extensions you need.